# What do these phpMyAdmin errors mean on my WordPress databaes?

Tags: posts, comments, database, errors, mysql

I'm getting 3 very similar phpMyAdmin errors on one of my WordPress databases.

```
More than one INDEX key was created for column `comment_approved`

More than one FULLTEXT key was created for column `post_title`

More than one INDEX key was created for column `lead_id`
```

Anyone know how to resolve these?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it writes, a problem with the indexes definitions of those tables. Please try a repair on the reported table and see if that helps.

Have you activated a specific add-on lately or did you alter tables?

Comment: Nope, that did not fix. I run a LOT of WordPress sites, add-ons and updates happen regularly.

Comment: If automatic repair does not work, you need to manually repair the indexes and remove the problematic parts of the named indexes.

Comment: Would exporting and importing using the WP core export and import functions fix it?